# Who is this guy in Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, rogue-one, actor-identification

Ever since I watched the movie, I've been scratching my head to figure out who this actor is. He somewhat reminds me of Adam Driver which makes things more irritating as he obviously isn't (and shouldn't be!) in the film. **Does anyone know the name of the actor or the character ?**

[image]
*(From the scene where general Draven orders a rebel squadron to bomb Eadu)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's Robin Pearce, credited as

> 'Rebel Tech'

on [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1131014/).

[image]

Comment: Well, we're allowed cheats like that here :) Good job to her then, her observation skills may have just earned you an accepted answer!

Comment: Thats it, finally!

Answer (score 3):

[image: Rufus Wright]

It *could be* Lieutenant Casido, played by Rufus Wright

Comment: Doesn't look like him IMO.

Comment: The guy in OPs picture looks South East Asian to me - definitely not Anglo.

Answer (score 0):

It *could* be Colonel Haxen Delto. Some background from *Rogue One: The Ultimate Visual Guide* :

> Delto oversees the specialists who scour the HoloNet and sub space transmissions for patterns and packets of useable intelligence. His methodical approach stands all in good stead.

[image]

It is difficult to tell. I'm basing this answer on his physical appearance, his contextual location (amongst the Rebel Alliance High Command), and the context of the situation in that scene. However, it's difficult to fully confirm without having the film in front of me for reference. However, upon closer examination of eyes and hair I think that my answer is lacking.

Comment: Haxen Delto is an asian guy with a ribbed jacket. This ain't him

Comment: @Valorum I definitely see a similarity between the two, although it's more than possible I am mistaken. Delto does indeed have ribbing on his shoulders and his hair is a little longer.

Comment: And he's ***Asian***. The guy in the pic above isn't.

Comment: @Withywindle As far I remember he had only a couple of scenes and a single dialog (something about the squadron already being engaged).

Comment: @Valorum on close inspection they aren't the same people. My answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Valorum do you have another pic to back that up? It's honestly kinda ambiguous in the OP's pic

Comment: @DBPriGuy it is a little difficult to tell but the eyes are very different and the hair is entirely wrong. The Visual Guide takes its pictures directly from the film so it can't be the same guy.

Comment: @Parsoa which is really interesting because the Visual Guide for R1 goes into detail about literally even the smallest character in the film. The fact that he actually (possibly) says something but doesn't appear to be in the book is surprising.

Answer (score 0):

In the novelization, Draven said "Squadron up" to a Captain Vienaris.
Later, it was Private Weems (the communication technician who later rushed to Mothma telling her there were Rebels on Scarif) who said "They are already engaged".

> *Draven swore inwardly and gestured rapidly at Weems. “Get the squadron leader on,” he said. “Get him on now!”
>
>   Weems looked as aghast as if he’d been accused of desertion. “They sent word three minutes ago. They’re already engaged, sir.”*

There is no Captain Vienaris in *Rogue One the Ultimate Visual Guide*, or in credits. The fact that the two notable actions/interactions this character did in the movie is attributed to two different characters in the novel makes me think that this character was unplanned.

I was itching to know who he is as well! The above may not be an answer (I wanted to add in a comment). I can't believe they overlooked a character as prominent as this guy, a character with spoken lines, when they credit likes of "Jedha server 1".

Comment: Looking at the image of Private Weems it seems unlikely to be him due to the mustache. An image of Captain Vienaris would be helpful, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: I know. My point is that in the novelization the two things this character did is attributed to two characters. - I'll add this to my answer to be clear.

Comment: I also removed the picture or Weems because I think it is distracting and I think people can recall who he is as he had a prominent scene with Mon Mothma, General Merrick and General Draven (and Chopper :P).

Comment: +1 for pointing out the inconsistency between the novelization and the actual movie.